# Upload image to s3 bucket with Cognito - react native Expo and node js

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, expo

I am building an app in React native (Expo) with a Node.js backend.  I want the user to upload a profile image from their phone to an S3 bucket, but I can never read the image after it uploads, it's always corrupted and cannot be read. I have tried lots a different variations and I think ChatGPT is leading me down wrong path.

Pseudo steps:

1. I am using AWS Cognito/IAM and have set all user roles/permissions and CORS to allow put, get, delete
2. getting pre-signedUrl from my backend, which appears to be working ok,
3. convert image to base64 then to binary format and upload to S3 bucket.

This all seems to "work", a file uploads with the correct file name that says its a 2Mb Jpeg, returns a Url - but I can never read the file.

Backend presigned Url:

```js
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const fileName = req.query["file-name"];
  const fileType = req.query["file-type"];
  const operation = req.query["operation"]; // determine if asking for get or push command

  console.log("filename input to preSignedUrl", fileName);

  try {
    let command;

    if (operation === "put") {
      command = new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: "test",
        Key: fileName,
        ContentType: fileType,
        
      });
    } else if (operation === "get") {
      command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: "test",
        Key: fileName,
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid operation." });
    }

    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
      expiresIn: 360, 
    });

    // Construct the return data
    const returnData = {
      signedRequest: signedUrl,
      url: `https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`,
    };

    console.log("data returned by presignedUrl", returnData); // debug returnedData
    res.json(returnData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to generate signed URL: ${error.message}" });
  }
});
```

Client side upload from react native app:

```js
const getPresignedUrlAndUpload = async (fileName, fileType, imageUri) => {
  try {
    // Read the file as binary data
    const fileData = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(imageUri, {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
    });

    const binaryData = new Uint8Array(
      fileData.split("").map((char) => char.charCodeAt(0))
    );
    // get presigned Url for upload to S3
    const response = await client.get(getPresignedUrlEndpoint, {
      "file-name": fileName,
      "file-type": fileType,
      operation: "put",
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Error getting presigned URL");
    }

    // Once you have the presigned URL, use it to upload the file
    const { signedRequest } = response.data;

    const uploadResponse = await fetch(signedRequest, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: binaryData,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": fileType,
      },
    });

    if (!uploadResponse.ok) {
      throw new Error("Error uploading file to S3");
    }

    // If everything went well, return the Object URL of the image
    return response.data.url;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in getPresignedUrlAndUpload: ", error);
    return null;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this myself in case it helps someone else.

Turns out with an EXPO managed workflow in React Native, converting Base64 image data to binary for upload is very difficult, tried so many ways and failed.

Without availability to use Blob (which is avaialable in non-managed workflow) it seems too difficult to try and upload an image to S3 from the client side.

By sending the Base64 data to the backend and using Node.js buffer to convert Base64 to binary, then using @aws-sdk/lib-storage, the image uploads successfully.  As long as you ensure the express.json size limit is high enough to receive your Base64 data, I changed mine to 10mB for single image, otherwise compress or resize the image before converting to Base64 and sending to backend.
Of course ensure AWS credentials are setup and policy on S3 bucket, IAM identify Pool is also setup for get, post etc.

example backend:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { Upload } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-storage");
const router = express.Router();

const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: "YOUR-REGION" });

router.use((req, res, next) => { // debug to check request body
  console.log(
    "Received request:",
    req.method,
    req.url,
    req.headers["content-type"]
  );
  next();
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const base64Data = req.body.fileData;
  const fileName = req.body.fileName;
  const fileType = req.body.fileType;

  console.log("data in request:", fileName);

  if (!base64Data) {
    return res.status(400).send("No image data received.");
  }

// check file size to see if any issues with express.json size limits for "payload too large errors"
  const bufferData = Buffer.from(base64Data, "base64");
  console.log("Size of fileData in bytes:", bufferData.length);

  // Convert Base64 to binary
  const binaryData = Buffer.from(base64Data, "base64");

  try {
    // Use the `Upload` utility from AWS SDK v3
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: "YOUR-BUCKET-NAME",
        Key: fileName,
        Body: binaryData,
        ContentType: fileType,
      },
    });

    await upload.done();

    res.json({
      url: `https://YOUR-BUCKET-NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`,
      message: "Upload successful!",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: `Failed to upload to S3: ${error.message}` });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```